# What is the difference between 0x and '\x' in C++?

Tags: c++

I know that hex-decimal number is usually prefixed with 0x in C/C++ language.
For example, `0x5A` means 90 in decimal.
But I saw an example code using single-quoted character with `'\x'`.

```
BYTE outputBuffer[index++] = '\x5A'; // instead of 0x5A
```

Is the meaning of `'\x5A'` exactly the same as `0x5A`?

If so, why is there alternative way of hex-decimal notation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547349/what-does-x-mean-in-c-c

Comment: Hex isn't limited to one byte for one.

Comment: Very good answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14264498/1673391

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a character, both are quite equal.

But only one can be mixed into a string with other normal characters.  `"ABC\x5A"`

And only one can be used to initialize a large integral type:  `long long x = 0x1234567812345678LL;`

Comment: In C++, '\x5A' is of type `char`, while 0x5A is of type `int`. They are not equal.

Comment: @C.R.: It's true that they have only value equality, not type equality.  But in the context of the question, being assigned to a variable of fixed type, we care about only the value and any value adjustments which take place as a result of widening or narrowing conversions.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry, it's indeed wrong, I've deleted my incorrect comment. Thanks for pointing it out.