# Convert escaped hexadecimal in string to int in c

Tags: c

Im trying to convert an escaped hexadecimal value to an integer. How should i do this.

I've tried it with `strtol` but this only produces the correct number if the hex is not escaped.

```
int number = (int)strtol("0x10", NULL, 16); //16
int number = (int)strtol("\x10", NULL, 16); //0
```

Comment: If you escape then the compiler will do the translation by itself, and then the *string* does not represent a correct hex value.

Comment: If you do this: `int n = "\x10"[0]; printf("%d\n", n);` you'll see that the escaped hex value is encoded *as is* into the character.

Comment: `"\x10"` is a string with a two characters, one with a value of `16` and other being the NUL-terminator. `"0x10"` is a proper NUL-terminated string representation of a hexadecimal number and what strtol expects to be passed as a argument. For your first case, to get the hexadecimal number, you need to do `(int)(*"\x10")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`"0x10"` means the C-string containing 4 characters (plus the ending NUL byte), `'0'`, followed by `'x'`, followed by `'1'`, followed by `'0'`.

`"\x10"` means the C-string containing 1 character (plus the ending NUL bytes), the sixteenth character of the ASCII table. The compiler interpret the content of your string by doing the conversion by itself, thus replacing the full sequence `\0x10` by its value. Then `strtol` is unable to understand this as a representation of an hex number representation, and then returns 0 :

> `strtol`manual : If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned
>   (0L).

Read [What does \x mean in c/c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547349/what-does-x-mean-in-c-c).