# How to I decode this weird string using Python or Java

Tags: java, python-3.x, encoding

I have an encoded string stored in my DB that kinda looks like this (altered for confidentiality):

```
\x7b22747c
```

How do I decode this string? (Using either Java or Python)

There is code elsewhere that used `tobytes()` function to decode it. But I don't own the code so I am not sure what it's doing.

Comment: That's probably an encoded Unicode character.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547349/what-does-x-mean-in-c-c

Comment: If it has an odd number of digits it's probably incorrect.

But it looks like a simple representation of a binary value. If it's supposed to be a string, you need to find which encoding it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments helped in looking in the right place.

Here is what worked for me:

`bytes.fromhex('7b22747').decode()`

So I just had to remove the `\x` and then just decode the remaining string which was an encoded hex string.